# Why am I still being asked for an ssh password when I'm using private key authentication?

Tags: ssh, openssh, putty

I have Linux mint on my pc.

I have a public/private key pair to ssh into my router without having to type the password.

It works on Windows using putty, but Mint isn't when I run it from terminal.

```
ssh -i privkey.ppk root@10.12.1.1
```

Comment: The debugging output you get with `-v`, `-vv` and maybe even `-vvv` might be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert keys generated by putty to a form that can be used by openssh.

There are several good answers explaining various ways of doing this at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224066/how-to-convert-ssh-keypairs-generated-using-puttygenwindows-into-key-pairs-use

Comment: I thought I also found some dupes here on U&L, but none of them were actual duplicates, just similar/related questions.