# Putty: Access denied

Tags: users, sshd, putty

My user id kranthi has been created and added to sudoers group.

I've made the following changes in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

```
PasswordAuthentication Yes
AllowUsers kranthi
```

In order to allow a user to ssh the user should be added to `AllowUsers`.

Port 22 is added to the sshd_config file.

`service sshd restart` was given.

Why cannot I SSH the server using putty ? What's missing ?

I get `access denied` after entering password.

After recommendation in comment section when I type

ssh -l kranthi 127.0.0.1 I got the following

The following is the screenshot from the console.

[image]

[image]
Still I cannot SSH the server using the user kranthi.

[image]

Comment: Sure ? The last line looks as if you were logged in. You would not get `last login` when rejected...

Comment: That's from console

Comment: Do not post images with a text. Also check the server log, which is usually more verbose about the reason for the authentication failure.

Answer (score 0):

Your server might be setup to disallow *password* authentication, e.g., requiring Kerberos ([not well supported](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/wishlist/kerberos-gssapi.html) by PuTTY), or a private key.

For the former, the `KerberosOrLocalPasswd` and `UsePAM` might be useful.

PuTTY works (except when Kerberos is intruding) well enough with a private key.

For reference:

- [sshd_config - OpenSSH SSH daemon configuration file](http://linux.die.net/man/5/sshd_config)
- [Configuring PuTTY for Kerberos - Based Authentication to 
  Linux & UNIX](https://www.centrify.com/resources/dsh-en-centrify-server-suite-technical-brief-configuring-putty-for-kerberos-based-authentication-to-linux-unix/)
- [Why am I still being asked for an ssh password when I'm using private key authentication?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/269452/why-am-i-still-being-asked-for-an-ssh-password-when-im-using-private-key-authen)

Answer (score 0):

Now I could putty to the VM. The VM is hosted on VMware and IP addresses is supplied through DCHP. After logging into the machine I could no see the IP address. Thus gave
`ifdown eth0`

`ifup eth0` .

Then tried putty again and that time it first time asked Yes/No question on finger print as I configured ssh key for root user. Then tried logging in as sudo user kranthi and see that I am inside the VM.

Strange!! What resolved the issue !!!